# How to prevent making objects of B class in any other way than in A class

Tags: c++, constructor

here's what I've got:

```
class A{
    B* object;
    const B& create_object(){
        if(object == nullptr)
            object = new B(this);
        return *object;
    }
}
```

Now, here's the thing. I am supposed not to allow creation of B in any other way than in A.
The only way I am allowed to create B objects is :

```
A a;
auto b1 = a.create_object();
```

Now as I am not supposed to allow the object creation I made all of B's constructors private and said that A is a friend of B.
HOWEVER when doing

```
auto b1 = a.create_object();
```

it doesnt compile as the copy constructor is called. Is there any way to avoid it? I don't want to return a pointer, it needs to be an object.

Comment: A a(); is a function declaration, by the way.

Comment: Your code example contradicts your claim. There are two intended ways to create a B object apparently: inside `create_object()`, and by copying the return value of `create_object`.

Comment: do not use `new` without a matching `delete`.  Heck, `new` period.

Comment: delete is invoked in A's destructor

Answer (score 6):

`b1` will be deduced to `B`, not to `const B&`, so compiler will check, that copy-ctor is available, use `const auto&` for this case

```
A a;
const auto& b1 = a.create_object();
```

Comment: What if the actual way the objects can be created is only auto b1 = a.create_object() ? What should I return/how should I do it?

Comment: @darenn: if you allow to make a copy of the object once (while initializing auto b1=...), why forbid second, third, etc. copy? Make copy ctor public or, alternatively, initialize a reference (w/o copying), as ForEveR suggests

Comment: @user396672 so theres no way to create an object this way without a copy ctor?

Comment: @darenn: No way. auto b1 is a separate object. not a reference. It can be initialized only using some _constructor_ (accessible from the point of declaration, so not private) .

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want with a proxy object:

```
class source_of_B
{
  class B &source;
  source_of_B(B &source): source(source) {}
  friend class A;
  friend class B;
};
```

Because it has no public constructors, creation of such object is restricted to its friends. So you can add public constructor to B that accepts the proxy without compromising your requirement to create B's at controlled locations:

```
class B
{
  int x;
  B(int x): x(x) {}
  friend class A;
public:
  B(const source_of_B &arg): x(arg.source.x) {}
};
class A
{
  B b;
public:
  A(): b(5) {}
  source_of_B create_object() { return source_of_B(b); }
};

int main()
{
  A a;
  B b = a.create_object();
}
```

but you can no longer use `auto b = a.create_object();` with this method.

**Edit**

If your compiler supports [return value optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization), which it probably does, you can go without the proxy. Just change `create_object()` to return `B` directly:

```
  B create_object() { return b; }

  auto b2 = a.create_object();
```

The copy constructor will be called by `create_object()` itself. The only problem would be that some (older) compilers have restrictions on the complexity of the function. See the Wikipedia article for example. Working example is at http://ideone.com/w1jKAd.

Comment: in this case auto b has type source_of_B, not B as OP assumes

Comment: @user396672 you are correct. `auto` can no longer be used here. Updated my answer.

Comment: well g++ 4.7 yells that im using a private constructor

Comment: I have g++ 4.8 here and it accepts both forms (the auto variant needs `--std=c++11` command-line switch). Visual Studio 2010 also appears to accept them.